# Should operations on RemoteViews be placed in the UI thread?

Tags: java, android

```java
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text,"Hello guys");
remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.text, View.GONE);
```

In notification, is it possible to ignore the UI thread?